# btn-next is not working when given inside a v-if and else condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am using vue js and html for my project and i am doing a registration. So, I have few tabs. For going to next-tab "btn-next" is the class needed. But, i need to move to next tab only if the json response i receive is true.

So, i modified my html as

```
<div class="wizard-footer">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <div v-if="response.status == false">
      <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary'>Submit Again</button></div>
    <div v-if="response.status == true">
      <button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary'>Next</button></div>
    <div v-else>
      <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I try this way.. i am not able to move to the next tab? can anybody please help me to have a solution..

I am able to get response and move through the different conditions but i am not able to move to next tab. it means btn-next is not working when i give inside div. So, please help me to find out a solution.

**My detailed code is**

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="step2">
  <form method="POST" id="form1" v-on:submit.prevent="handleSubmit($event);">
    <div class="row p-b-15  ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Contact Name :</label>
              <input name="cname" type="text" class="form-control" id="cname" placeholder="Contact Name" required="required" v-model="cname" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wizard-footer">
        <div class="pull-right">
          <div v-if="response.status == false"><button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary'>Next</button></div>
          <div v-if="response.status == true"><button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary'>Next</button></div>
          <div v-else>
            <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary'>Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**My vue js code**

```
submitBox = new Vue({
  el: "#submitBox",

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    var vm = this;
    data = {};
    data['name'] = this.cname;
    data['pid'] = this.pid;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'hpost/contact/',
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(e) {
        if (e.status) {
         vm.response = e;
          console.log(vm.response);
          alert("Registration Success")

        } else {
          vm.response = e;
          console.log(vm.response);
          alert("Registration Failed")
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  },
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Perhaps `response` is initially `null`?

Comment: no error sir. initially i will go to v-else condition

Comment: Could you clarify "I am able to get response and move through the different conditions but i am not able to move to next tab"? Where is your tab code/template? How are you handling the button clicks (do you have `<form @submit.prevent="...">`?).

Comment: i will update my code sir

Comment: sir, i updated my code

Comment: What is the initial value of `response` in the component? In the AJAX success callback, if `e.status` is truthy then you're not assigning to `vm.response` so the `response.status == true` condition in the template won't change. When you say you can't "move to the next tab", what do you mean exactly? I can't see any tabs in your template, which I expect should have `v-if="step === 1"` or something like that if you require multiple steps (like a wizard interface).

Comment: may i add my full code for you

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

If the buttons are rendered correctly, please check your web server's backend code. I find that you are rendering a form with two "submit" buttons, maybe the backend does not know which submit is your expectation.

when `response.status == false`: Submit Again and Submit are rendered

when `response.status == true`: Next is rendered

but they are all normal submit buttons, does your backend or `handleSubmit` know that?

Case 2:

If the buttons are not rendered correctly, please check your JSON structure and vue syntax.